# Load File on Android

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I want load a file wav from sdcard in my android project but I don't succeed.
 I'm using

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"/mnt/sdcard/.....wav");
```

but I get this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/......wav (No such file or directory)
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: No such file or directory in the path you are look, and give the permission too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first parameter is already the path - do not put /mnt/sdcard/ to the second parameter

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,".....wav");
```

Comment: glad I could help - perhaps you could accept the answer then

Answer (score 1):

Remove this `/mnt/sdcard/` from the line It is already there in `file`

Replace this:

```
File file = new File(sdcard,"/mnt/sdcard/.....wav");
```

with this:

```
File file = new File(sdcard,".....wav");
```